# Android - BroadcastReceiver not calling

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

when i was register the broadcast receiver, `onReceive` was not called. here is my code

```
    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.v("sunil", "broadcastreceiver======");

        }
    };
```

Comment: You should add some actions to that `IntentFilter`. What kind of actions you want to listen for?

Comment: i don't want any action. need to execute only onReceive. i need to compare previous time and current time in onreceive

Comment: I think you are not understanding the concept of `BroadcastReceiver`s. These are for cases when you want to do something when an event (broadcast) occurs. For example some part of your app calls `sendBroadcast()` with the relevant `Intent`.

Also registering in `onUserInteraction()` is a very bad idea, also not using any proper filter. You should really read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to look for a string just to tell the android what are you trying to looking for , for example if you want to try some code on on receive you should use a string in you intentfiltre

```
      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
```